# StringBuilder appending first row of a datatable repeatedly

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, stringbuilder

I am trying to build an html table from a datatable that contains 24 months of a customer's payment history. However, only the first row of data is returned (most recent payment) and is repeated 24 times. The Select statement returns 24 distinct rows when run in the query builder. is the foreach loop writing over itself? I don't think that I am overloading the stringbuilder with only 24 rows. I tried adding AppendLine(); but it doesn't change anything.

```
        //get account history

        String strConnString7 = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["billing_webConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con7 = new SqlConnection(strConnString7);
        SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.WEB_HISTORY WHERE acct_nbr ='" + AcctNbr + "'ORDER BY billing_date DESC", con7);
        cmd7.Parameters.Add("conn_nbr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session["AcctNum"];
        cmd7.Connection = con7;
        SqlDataAdapter da7 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd7);
        DataTable dtHistory = new DataTable();
        da7.Fill(dtHistory);


        if (dtHistory != null && dtHistory.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string Billing_Date = String.Format("{0:d}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["billing_date"]);
            string W_Cons = dtHistory.Rows[0]["w_cons"].ToString();
            string W_Curr_Chrg = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["w_curr_chrg"]);
            string S_Curr_Chrg = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["s_curr_chrg"]);
            string Adjs = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["adjs"]);
            string Pay = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["pay"]);
            string Return_pay = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["return_pay"]);


           System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dtHistory.Rows)   
            {

                sb.Append("<tr><td>" + Billing_Date + "</td><td>" + W_Cons + "</td><td>" + W_Curr_Chrg + "</td><td>" + S_Curr_Chrg + "</td><td>" + Adjs + "</td><td>" + Pay + "</td><td>" + Return_pay + "</td></tr>");

                }


            History.Text = sb.ToString();
            //Counter.Text = counter.ToString();
            con7.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over every row, but you only set `Billing_Date`, `W_Cons`, `W_Curr_Chrg`, `S_Curr_Chrg`, `Adjs`, `Pay`, and `Return_pay` once:

```
        string Billing_Date = String.Format("{0:d}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["billing_date"]);
        string W_Cons = dtHistory.Rows[0]["w_cons"].ToString();
        string W_Curr_Chrg = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["w_curr_chrg"]);
        string S_Curr_Chrg = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["s_curr_chrg"]);
        string Adjs = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["adjs"]);
        string Pay = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["pay"]);
        string Return_pay = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["return_pay"]);
```

When you loop through the rows, you're appending them every time, but you're not actually updating them -- so their value never changes from what you originally set it to.

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dtHistory.Rows)   
        {
            sb.Append("<tr><td>" + Billing_Date + "</td><td>" + W_Cons + "</td><td>" + W_Curr_Chrg + "</td><td>" + S_Curr_Chrg + "</td><td>" + Adjs + "</td><td>" + Pay + "</td><td>" + Return_pay + "</td></tr>");
        }
```

You need to update their values in that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are using fixed data inside the `foreach` loop.

For example, `Billing_Date` is set at the top, outside the loop, so will always contain the same value.

The loop needs to access your `row` variable to get data from each row.

Answer (score 1):

you are looping over each row:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtHistory.Rows)
```

but inside your loop, you are never using that `row` object

```
sb.Append("<tr><td>" + Billing_Date + "</td><td>" + W_Cons + "</td><td>" + W_Curr_Chrg + "</td><td>" + S_Curr_Chrg + "</td><td>" + Adjs + "</td><td>" + Pay + "</td><td>" + Return_pay + "</td></tr>");
```

instead of `Billing_Date` i assume you're wanting `row["billing_date"]`, etc.

As an aside note, you are doing a whole lot of string concatenation inside your `sb.Append`.  You should append each item separately and avoid the heavy concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all your below variables hold references to the `Rows[0]` values. You need to change it to retrieve the values for the respective data rows and build the StringBuilder.

```
string Billing_Date = String.Format("{0:d}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["billing_date"]);
string W_Cons = dtHistory.Rows[0]["w_cons"].ToString();
string W_Curr_Chrg = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["w_curr_chrg"]);
string S_Curr_Chrg = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["s_curr_chrg"]);
string Adjs = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["adjs"]);
string Pay = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["pay"]);
string Return_pay = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dtHistory.Rows[0]["return_pay"]);
```

So your `if` statement will become

```
if (dtHistory != null && dtHistory.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   foreach (DataRow row in dtHistory.Rows)   
   {
      string Billing_Date = String.Format("{0:d}", row["billing_date"]);
      string W_Cons = dtHistory.row["w_cons"].ToString();
      string W_Curr_Chrg = String.Format("{0:0.00}", row["w_curr_chrg"]);
      string S_Curr_Chrg = String.Format("{0:0.00}", row["s_curr_chrg"]);
      string Adjs = String.Format("{0:0.00}", row["adjs"]);
      string Pay = String.Format("{0:0.00}", row["pay"]);
      string Return_pay = String.Format("{0:0.00}", row["return_pay"]);
      sb.Append("<tr><td>" + Billing_Date + "</td><td>" + W_Cons + "</td><td>" + W_Curr_Chrg + "</td><td>" + S_Curr_Chrg + "</td><td>" + Adjs + "</td><td>" + Pay + "</td><td>" + Return_pay + "</td></tr>");
   }

      History.Text = sb.ToString();
      con7.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked perfectly! I am new to .Net coming from asp, so I figured I was tripping up on syntax. Overlooked the indexing, did not know you could call a row without it. That was an excellent lesson.

Comment: @BillD If the answer really helped you solve the issue then you can mark it as answer by clicking the the `right tick` availabel at the left side of the answer. Here is how [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer works